# HTTP to HTTPS redirect loop

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, http, https

*Firstly, I know there is a million of copies of this question already but after hours of trying solutions from all of them I've got nowhere.*

So I want to redirect all incoming HTTP traffic on my Apache web server to HTTPS. I've tried several approaches and most of them have had 1 of 2 results: a) a redirect loop or b) only the very top-level page is redirected (i.e no directories get sent to HTTPS).

My current virtualhost file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>  
    <VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName roboguy99.co.uk
    Redirect / https://roboguy99.co.uk/
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin roboguy99@gmail.com
    ServerAlias www.roboguy99.co.uk
        ServerName roboguy99.co.uk
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This current config is causing a redirect loop.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Possibly useful information:**

- Apache 2.2.22
- Running on Debian (Raspberry Pi)
- Accessing from Windows 8.1, Google Chrome

*I'm away for the week so if I don't reply to any questions, that's why. I'm also going to remove the redirect while I'm away, so live-testing the site won't work at the moment.*

Comment: Where did you get `ServerAlias https:// www.roboguy99.co.uk`? Remove the `https://` from [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias).

Comment: I think it was a failed test from earlier. I've removed it, and I'm getting the same result.

Comment: I see a few problems with your configuration, but none that would explain a redirect loop. Your `IfModule` block hasn't been closed. Your first vhost is missing a `ServerName`. The second vhost has a incorrectly formatted `ServerAlias`. What's missing from your question is which URLs are in the redirect loop? And do you have any `.htaccess` file, which could explain the problem?

Comment: I have a .htaccess file, although it's currently empty. The other things I will fix now, thanks. Do I need both this type of redirect and a RewriteRule in the .htaccess for it to work? EDIT: The IfModule is closed, I just missed it when copying the file :|

Comment: Your site is behind CloudFlare? is a wordpress?

Comment: No, I've got no scripts installed. The closest thing to a script I have is Bootstrap, but that's different...

Answer (score 1):

Add those lines in *VirtualHost *:80*:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Make sure you enabled *mod_rewrite*:

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Check result with *wget*:

```
wget --spider domain.tld
```

Comment: I've tried this and my site no longer is accessible. On chrome it leads to example.com (a cached copy?) and on IE fails to load.

Comment: Update: Tested on Chrome on another device, it's giving me a redirect loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change your

```
Redirect / https://roboguy99.co.uk/
```

To

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://roboguy99.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

On your first one you only redirect when user requests **/** with the one I propose to you you will redirect all and furturmore add whatever user requested after **/**